# How to check if two password input field values are equal and greater than zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<div>` elements with the IDs `"pswd_info"` and `"pswd_confirm"` and two password fields.

I am wanting something like:

1. When field one is focused, div 1 will show and will add values
2. Again, when the second field is focused, div 2 will show and add values
3. If both field values are equal, none of the divs will show

Problem I am facing is, non of these divs are showing up as initially two values of the fields are zero (0).
So how can I write a condition like: Both fields need to be equal and their value needs to be greater than 0, then will hide the divs.

**[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/B68d9/)**

```
// Field 1 
$("input[type=password][name='pass']").keyup(function () {
    }).focus(function () {
        $('#pswd_info').show();
});

// Field 2
$("input[type=password][name='cpass']").keyup(function () {
    }).focus(function () {
        $('#pswd_confirm').show();
});

/*------------------------------------------------*/

if (  $("#txtPassword").val() == $("#txtPassword2").val() ) {

    $("input[type=password][name='cpass']").focus(function () {
        $('#pswd_confirm').hide();
    });

    $("input[type=password][name='pass']").focus(function () {
        $('#pswd_info').hide();
    });
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. (Sorry for the bad English)

Comment: Thanks For the Edit. Sorry not very good in English.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to call a checkSame function on keyup.

```
//field 1 
$("input[type=password][name='pass']").keyup(checkSame).focus(function () {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
});

//field 2
$("input[type=password][name='cpass']").keyup(checkSame).focus(function () {
    $('#pswd_confirm').show();
});

/*------------------------------------------------*/
function checkSame() {
    if ($("#txtPassword").val() == $("#txtPassword2").val() && $("#txtPassword").val().length != 0) {
            $('#pswd_confirm').hide();
            $('#pswd_info').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is Almost what I was wanting But One thing is if the values of the both field are equal DIV will never show up if I focus any input.

With your example when values are equal DIV did hides but it again come back if I focus again. Which should not come back till the values are same.

Comment: I made a change to the code so that it checks for sameness first then shows the div when focused.